# Solving a differential equation: two different forms of the same answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I get given some information and have to find an equation for y in terms of X. I get the answer which is cool, but in the exam mark scheme they give a different answer which turns out to be in fact the same answer.

I wouldn't care so much if it wasn't for the obvious advantage the other form has over my form. The next question asks what happens to Y as X tends to infinity. I just need somebody to explain what's going on. (I know it has something to do with the way I compute the constant c in Ln form.)

The question: $dy/dx=y(4-y)$.  And when $X = 0$, $Y=1$. 
So I integrate $\frac{1}{y(4-y)}$ and get the form $\frac{1}{4}\ln(\frac{y}{4-y})+c$. But to make things easier I put c into log form as "LnA"

Then I solve for c  and get $\ln{A}$ as $\frac{1}{4}\ln{3}$.

Then I rearrange and get $Y=\frac{4e^{4x}}{e^{4x}+3}$ as a final answer. But the mark scheme answer gives $\frac{4}{3e^{-4x}+1}$.

The problem here is that it is very easy to see with the second form that Y will tend to 4 if X tends to infinity. So the second form reveals more. But it looks so different. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Multiply top and bottom of your answer by $e^{-4x}$, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @gregory said, all they've done is simplified.

$$Y=\frac{4e^{4x}}{e^{4x}+3}$$

Take out a factor of $e^{4x}$ from the top and from the bottom gives

$$Y=\frac{e^{4x}}{e^{4x}}\frac{4}{1+\frac{3}{e^{4x}}}$$
$$Y=1\cdot\frac{4}{1+3e^{-4x}}$$
$$Y=\frac{4}{1+3e^{-4x}}$$ as required.

Comment: on a side note, depending on the marker you MAY lose a single mark for not simplifying it fully.

Comment: Oh beautiful thanks guys I completely understand it now

Answer (score 2):

Observe that multiplication of numerator and denominator by $ e^{-4x} $ simplified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are completely equivalent, and I personally would not consider one significantly simpler than the other.  If I were your prof, you would get full marks for this answer.  I think you would be quite justified in complaining about this.

Comment: in all honesty i agree with you, but some markers are touchy about what they consider convention. take my university for example. it's only been recently that we've been able to get transcripts back to the students as such you wont know unless you've requested it back.(the exam)